# Angular redirect to an empty page after the button is clicked

Tags: angular, button

I have a home  page with  one button , when the user click in the button  the user must be redirected to another page.
I try to make it like this but nothing happen when i click the button:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'SaveWorld';
  constructor(private router:Router){}

 onClick(){
this.router.navigateByUrl('/saveWorld');
   }
}
```

Button code :

```
<button  click)="onClick()"type="button" class="button" >Make a change</button>
```

routes

```
import {NgModule} from  '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from  '@angular/router';
import {HomePageComponent} from  '../app/home-page/home-page.component'

const routes:Routes=[

     {path:'HomePage',component:HomePageComponent},
    {path:'saveWorld',component:SaveWorldComponent},
    {path:'',redirectTo:'/HomePage',pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports:[RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Can you please help me?

Update:

Now when  i click the button  works but not how i want to work,didn't redirect me to a new empty page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYSMw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have `typo` in your path/goto. Change it to `HomePage` or `homePage`, but not mixed.

Comment: Thank you, but still have the problem.

Comment: Can you explain more? Please be more precise and descriptive about your issue so some can help you.

Comment: Now the path change  and show me what i have in the html  but i don't know why i have the input of the html home page and didn't redirect me to a new page.

Comment: I solved it,the problem was that i didn't call <router-outlet> on the app.component.html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html.
Take a look on this https://angular.io/guide/router, it might help you.